# Kubernetes CRD versioning

Tags: kubernetes

Kuberentes has a mechanism for supporting versioning of CRDs. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/custom-resources/custom-resource-definition-versioning/. What is not clear to me is how you actually support an evolution of CRD v1 to CRD v2 when you cannot always convert from v1 <-> v2. Suppose we introduce a new field in v2 that can not be populated by a web hook conversion, then perhaps all we can do is leave the field null? Furthermore when you request api version N you always get back an object as version N even if it was not written as version N so how can you controller know how to treat the object?

Comment: As it described in documentation you should mark versions by yourself and then you have possibility to use it

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation where it says you should mark versions by yourself?

Comment: This part speaks about [specifying multiple versions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/custom-resources/custom-resource-definition-versioning/#specify-multiple-versions), please read if carefully.

Comment: I have read the link (I included it in my original post)...I don't believe it answers my question. Neither does marking a version as the storage version. The key point in my question is how can you support evolving from v1 to v2 if you cannot convert in a web hook. The example of splitting or merging host and port is trivial. But what if v2 has some filed that can be derived from data in v1.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in [Writing, reading, and updating versioned CustomResourceDefinition objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definition-versioning/#writing-reading-and-updating-versioned-customresourcedefinition-objects)

> If you update an existing object, it is rewritten at the version that is currently the storage version. This is the only way that objects can change from one version to another.

Kubernetes returns the object to you at the version you requested, but the persisted object is neither changed on disk, nor converted in any way (other than changing the apiVersion string) while serving the request.

If you update an existing object, it is rewritten at the version that is currently the storage version. This is the only way that objects can change from one version to another.

You read your object at version `v1beta1`, then you read the object again at version `v1`. Both returned objects are identical except for the `apiVersion` field, [Upgrade existing objects to a new stored version](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/custom-resources/custom-resource-definition-versioning/#upgrade-existing-objects-to-a-new-stored-version)

The API server also supports webhook conversions that call an external service in case a conversion is required.
The webhook handles the ConversionReview requests sent by the API servers, and sends back conversion results wrapped in ConversionResponse. You can read about Webbooks [here](https://book.kubebuilder.io/beyond_basics/what_is_a_webhook.html).

Webhook conversion was introduced in `Kubernetes v1.13` as an alpha feature.
When the webhook server is deployed into the Kubernetes cluster as a service, it has to be exposed via a service on port 443.
When deprecating versions and dropping support, devise a storage upgrade procedure.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you describe I think you are forced to define some kind of 'default' value for that new mandatory field being introduced, so custom objects created before that change can be converted to the updated spec.
But then it becomes a backward compatible change, so no need to define that v2, you can remain in v1.

If It Is not possible to define a default value for it nor to derive any value at all (for that mandatory introduced field) from other fields existing in a custom object compliant with current v1 (i.e. the schema to follow before introducing this update) then you should assure v2 to be the new stored versione and then manually update all existing v1 compliant custom objects to properly set that mandatory parameter.
Or even to define a new custom object ...

Answer (score -1):

Let say you have CRD specification like below.

```
// API v6.
type Frobber struct {
  Height int    `json:"height"`
  Param  string `json:"param"`
}
```

Then you added some new spec called `Width`.

```
// Still API v6.
type Frobber struct {
  Height int    `json:"height"`
  Width  int    `json:"width"`
  Param  string `json:"param"`
}
```

So as long as you can handle this change using controller logic you do not need any version change. Which means this addition would be backward compatible.

But let say now you are changing the previous spec as below.

```
// Internal, soon to be v7beta1.
type Frobber struct {
  Height int
  Width  int
  Params []string
}
```

Here you change an existing spec which is not backward compatible. Also, you might not handle this change using controller logic. In these kinds of changes, it is better to use a version upgrade.

For more details about kubernetes API version changes, refer the following links.

[1] https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api_changes.md

[2] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/operator-framework/jswZUe1rlho

Comment: What you describe is the change of a CR, not a CRD. OP asked about CRD versioning. CRDs define a list of supported versions in their respective spec for which you can implement webhook conversions and the like.